# rake db:migrate giving exception, rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I cloned a repo from bitbucket now trying to set it up on localhost machine.

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: test_123: ALTER TABLE "test_123" ADD "icon_file_name"

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

But still getting that same issue. What is solution for this?

Comment: There must be a migration file, which tries to `alter table test_123`. Two questions:
1. Are you creating table test_123 ever in your migration?
2. If yes, please mention the migration version for the files, which alters table test_123, and the one which creates test_123.

Comment: didn't get you @UtsavKesharwani

Comment: please add the migration file which raises this error.

Comment: `rake db:reset` worked for me. Thanks